# Confusion with node_modules being ignored by .dockerignore

Tags: node.js, docker

Thought I'd just wanted to share this.  So I am testing creation of a docker image/container with a nodejs app usiung Dockerfile.  Everything went smoothly, until I tried to add the .dockerignore file, where I listed the following files in it, expecting that they won't get copied into the docker image:

```
node_modules 
dockerignore 
Dockerfile
```

And here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /app
ADD . .
RUN npm install
CMD node index.js
```

So I trashed and rebuilt my image with the existing Dockerfile and the new .dockerignore file.  After the creation, I ran `docker run -it --entrypoint sh <image name>` to check if those files/folders do not appear anymore.

`Dockerfile` and `.dockerignore` are gone.  But `node_modules` folder is still there.

Took me a while to "realize" that MAYBE the `node_modules` folder in the image is created by the Dockerfile's `npm install` step, not the folder copied from the host anyway.

Am I right?

Comment: `Took me a while to "realize" that maybe the node_modules folder in the image is created by the Dockerfile's npm install step, not the folder copied from the host anyway. Am I right?` Yes.

Comment: tkausl, so what if I don't include the `node_modules` inside the `.dockerignore` file?   Does the `node_modules` folder get overwritten anyway when the `npm install` gets executed?   So there is no need to include `node_modules` in `.dockerignore` after all?

Comment: It's potentially large, and slows the build down; the `ADD . .` step will copy it in, so you'll get a larger image; if the host and container aren't the same OS there's a potential for wrong-architecture modules to still be installed.

Comment: @DavidMaze, could you kindly review my answer and add comments to it?  I want to make sure i get it correctly.

Answer (score 9):

So I got the answer based on tkausl and David Maze's comments (thanks guys!) .

The `node_modules` inside the image is generated from the Dockerfile 'npm install' step.

And as for the question:

> if `.dockerignore` does not include `node_modules`, Dockerfile would
> have overwritten `node_modules` anyway?  So why bother to put `node_modules` inside the .dockerignore file?

the comment I received was that if I left out the node_modules from the .dockerignore file,  then the docker build process would have slowed down due to unnecessary copying of the `node_modules`, PLUS the image would have been larger.

Therefore, the prudent thing is to keep `node_modules` inside `.dockerignore` file to achieve more efficiency in the `docker build` process.

UPDATE: I did try to run the scenario with the `node_modules` removed from .dockerignore file, and the image is showing 940MB,  whereas creating the image with `node_modules` inside the `.dockerignore` file - though the process may be more efficient - the output image is 942MB (2MB larger).

Comment: I have a similar observation i.e. with or without the node_modules included in the .dockerignore file, the image size is the same. In both cases, I see a message while running the build "transferring context: 490.12kB". That's pretty insignificant and surely it's not transferring the node_modules folder. What does it mean to have a more efficient build? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Consider docker as a entire new box, where everything will be installed and given commands to run specific tasks

In this case, try two things

1. Create .dockerignore file and ignore all files which you think you don't want to include or let docker handles from itself.

   .git

   */node_modules

   ####### other files...
2. And in Dockerfile just copy package.json as docker it use for deployment, so it makes sense that only package.json file will get change. So try adding
   COPY package*.json ./ in Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I was having issues with certain node_modules not being available when using Docker.

The problem was that they were present in the app, so copying the package didn't help, but they were not available to the Docker Compose VM.

I ran `docker-compose build --no-cache` before upping my compose instance to include them in the VM, and they were then available.

Maybe this can avoid someone scratching their head for hours like I did.